# How to get $_GET parameters in MVC

Tags: php, .htaccess

Sry for my english in advance, guys. Got a MVC-frame, making a website on that. 
.htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Router.php:

```
 class Router
{

    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $routesPath = ROOT.'/config/routes.php';
        $this->routes = include($routesPath);
    }

// Return type

    private function getURI()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        return trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $uri = $this->getURI();

        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {

            if(preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {


                $internalRoute = preg_replace("~$uriPattern~", $path, $uri);

                $segments = explode('/', $internalRoute);

                //Search name for controller we need
                $controllerName = array_shift($segments).'Controller';
                $controllerName = ucfirst($controllerName);

                //Находим название action
                $actionName = 'action'.ucfirst((array_shift($segments)));

                $parameters = $segments;
                $controllerFile = ROOT . '/controllers/' .$controllerName. '.php';
                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    include_once($controllerFile);
                }
                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;
                $result = call_user_func_array(array($controllerObject, $actionName), $parameters);
                if ($result != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

routes.php (array for controller and routes)

```
 <?php
return array(
    'admin/product/update/([0-9]+)' => 'adminProduct/update/$1',
    'admin/product/delete/([0-9]+)' => 'adminProduct/delete/$1',
    'admin/products/create' => 'adminProduct/create',
    'admin/products' => 'adminProduct/index',
    'admin' => 'admin/index',
    'login' => 'user/login',

    'product/([\w]{1,})' => 'product/view/$1',
    'category/([\w]{1,})' => 'site/category/$1',
    '([\s\S\w\W\d\D]{1,})' => 'site/error',
    '' => 'site/index/$1',
);
```

Problem: $_GET parameters isn't work, because Router.php cant search `?asd=asd` in routes.php. 
For example: link `site/?utm_sourse=vk` doesnt work, because Router.php recognizes it as `'([\s\S\w\W\d\D]{1,})' => 'site/error'`. What should I do to get the $_GET params in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change `Router::getURI()` to strip off any query string before returning it. Not tested, but something along these lines:

```
private function getURI()
{
    $uri = '';

    if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }

    if (($cutoff = strpos($uri, '?')) !== false) {
        $uri = substr($uri, 0, $cutoff);
    }

    return trim($uri, '/');
}
```